# How to send image ( blob ) into db with FormBuilder

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I got a problem with uploading a file blob into the same DB with my Form.

There is my form

```
this.accForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  team_leader: ['', Validators.required],
  hotel_name: ['', Validators.required],
  address: ['', Validators.required],
  report_person: ['', Validators.required],
  room: ['', Validators.required],
  description: ['', Validators.required],
  incident_person: ['', Validators.required],
  damage_notification: ['', Validators.required],
  damage_photo: ['', Validators.required],
  photo: ['', Validators.required],
  comments: ['', Validators.required],
  check_in: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/)]],
  check_out: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/)]],
  incident_date: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/)]],
}, {
});
```

There is my html input where I am gettint a file

```
 <input type="file" class="form-control" id="damage_photo"
                        (change)="selectFile($event)">
```

and there are my functions to selectFile and upload

```
 selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  }

  get f() { return this.accForm.controls; }


  onSubmit() {
    
    this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
//Tried also something like
this.accForm.value.photo = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.accForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.accidentFormService.saveAccidentForm(this.accForm.value).subscribe(
      res => {
      console.log(res);
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
    this.selectedFiles = undefined;
  }
```

And also my service to upload

```
  saveAccidentForm(accidentForm: AccidentForm): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/accident-form', accidentForm,  {
    });
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

If I want to upload just file my service looks like

```
  pushFileToStorageAccidentForm(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();

    formdata.append('file', file);

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/accident-form', formdata, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'text'
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

And it works fine but how Can i send at the same time my form and file blob?

Answer (score 0):

You can append more properties to formdata. In this case maybe formdata.append('data', this.accForm.value) I think it works! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
onFileChanged(input) {
     let data='';
     var reader;

  if (input.srcElement.files[0] && (input.srcElement.value.endsWith('jpg') || input.srcElement.value.endsWith('png'))) {
    reader = new FileReader();
    this.SpecialImagePassing= input.srcElement.files[0] as File;//as a file important
    reader.onload = function(e) {
  
     data=e.target.result;
     
    
    }
   
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.srcElement.files[0]);
  }
  }
```

this is a way of getting blob but i highly suggest you to use [multer.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for file uploads and saving because you cant assign blob without using sanitizing function in angular and sometimes the db rejects the excessive size of blob

Comment: I am using multer on my backend. If I want just send file from my front I am using in my service: const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
formdata.append('file', file);

But here I got file and form from formBuilder

Comment: there's no error. Just I am sending empty empty value and my backend gaves me 500.
Cause I am sending accidentForm and there is no blob string I think

Comment: this.SpecialImagePassing= input.srcElement.files[0] as File